# Python split by regular expression

Tags: python, regex, email, split

In Python, I am extracting emails from a string like so:

```
split = re.split(" ", string)
emails = []

pattern = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+$");

for bit in split:
    result = pattern.match(bit)

    if(result != None):
        emails.append(bit)
```

And this works, as long as there is a space in between the emails. But this might not always be the case. For example:

`Hello, foo@foo.com`

would return:

`foo@foo.com`

but, take the following string:

`I know my best friend mailto:foo@foo.com!`

This would return `null`. So the question is: how can I make it so that a regex is the delimiter to split? I would want to get

`foo@foo.com`

in all cases, regardless of punctuation next to it. Is this possible in Python?

By "splitting by regex" I mean that if the program encounters the pattern in a string, it will extract that part and put it into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you're looking for [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> email_reg = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+')
>>> email_reg.findall('I know my best friend mailto:foo@foo.com!')
['foo@foo.com']
```

Notice that `findall` can handle more than one email address:

```
>>> email_reg.findall('Text text foo@foo.com, text text, baz@baz.com!')
['foo@foo.com', 'baz@baz.com']
```

Comment: At least don't forget to escape the only `.` that needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Qtax: Thanks, I've made the change. As I said regex are not my best, if you still see somethings wrong don't hesitate to edit or to let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search` or `re.findall`.
You also need to escape your expression properly (`.` needs to be escaped outside of character classes, not inside) and remove/replace the anchors `^` and `$` (for example with `\b`), eg:

```
r"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\b"
```

Comment: "\b" at the beginning and the end will not work for mailto:foo@foo.com!.

Comment: @marue, have you tried it? It will work just fine. `:` is not a word character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see in your regex is your use of `^` which matches the start of a string and `$` which matches the end of your string. If you remove it and then run it with your sample test case it will work

```
>>> re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+.[A-Za-z0-9-\.]+","I know my best friend mailto:foo@foo.com!")
['foo@foo.com']
>>> re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+.[A-Za-z0-9-\.]+","Hello, foo@foo.com")
['foo@foo.com']
>>>
```

Comment: Your regex is missing a `+` at the end.

Comment: Was that fixed (it could have happened within the edit grace period)? If it was, please flag both comments for deletion.